# Highlight streets using Static Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to use the static maps API to highlight sections of streets on a map. The problem is that the map simply renders a straight line which sometimes goes off the street. Instead, I want it to highlight the actual street. I know I can use the google directions API for this but I'm rendering the generated map to a PDF so a static map seems like the logical choice.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=weight:5|1432%20Dana%20Avenue%20Palo%20alto|1532%20dana%20avenue%20palo%20alto&sensor=false

Comment: Have you tried adding an [encoded polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?csw=1#EncodedPolylines) that follows the street?  You can get one from the directions service (but that would make this a two part process).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a polyline that follows the street, request directions between the 2 addresses:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Dana%20Avenue%20Palo%20alto&destination=1532%20dana%20avenue%20palo%20alto&sensor=false
```

[Example directions request](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Dana%20Avenue%20Palo%20alto&destination=1532%20dana%20avenue%20palo%20alto&sensor=false)

Use the "overview_polyline" returned in that request:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=weight:5|enc:__rcF~tnhVpDiPVc@\o@t@{B&sensor=false
```

example with polyline that follows the street

[http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=weight:5|enc:__rcF~tnhVpDiPVc@\o@t@{B&sensor=false](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=weight:5%7Cenc%3a__rcF~tnhVpDiPVc@%5Co@t@%7BB&sensor=false)